# Solr tokenizer for search

Tags: solr, lucene

I have defined a new field type in Solr for a auto suggest,

```
 <fieldType name="auto_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

now if I search for a particular field for example

```
 /solr/select?q=ree
```

Im able to get the response like "reebok shirt" but not able to fetch the records like "white reebok shirt", should I add any other tokenizer to acheive the same???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory). KeywordTokenizerFactory does this: *Treats the entire field as a single token, regardless of its content.* Use [WhitespaceTokenizerFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory) instead.